# R script while windows system is locked

Tags: r, windows-7-x64

I need to know what will happen if I am running an R script which takes typically say 30 to 45 minutes to execute and during that time my windows 7 system gets locked. Will it effect the R script execution in any way? or will I have the complete and accurate R script execution if I unlock my system after say 2 or 3 hours or just after the R script execution time.

Comment: This seems like a good problem for a self test. Execute the script and lock the screen yourself. Later, check-in and see if the script produces the intended results.

Comment: ... and it is something that will potentially be unique for each person. For example, some computers may be configured to lock *and go to sleep*, while others may just lock and dim the screen while allowing the CPUs to keep chugging away.